# Run Xamarin studio 5.0.0 on OSX Lion 10.7.x

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Please I did like to know if the latest Xamarin Studio runs on OS X Lion 10.7.5. I really need this info because someone told me it requires OS X Mountain Lion at the very minimum, which however i cannot verify

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.iOS requires XCode 5, which requires Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8).

Comment: I have used Xamarin.IOS With XCode4.x before. I am wondering if that is the case with the latest release